# Area of the intersection of two cones

Tags: integration, geometry

I would like to find an expression for the area of the intersection of the two cones shown in the following figure:

[image]

The axes of both cones are situated on the plane YZ, and the angles are respectively $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, while the angle of the intersection is $\theta$, as indicated in the picture. Obviously, I'm interested in the case when $\alpha_1+\alpha_2<\theta$, since otherwise there would be no intersection between the cones.

My idea is to do it by integration on the sphere, but how can I find the limits I need for the integral?

Comment: It is not clear if the area is on the sphere or on the surface of the cones. From the figure, I understand it is on the sphere. From the text I understand it is on the cones.

Comment: The area is on the cones. Sorry, English is not my first language and I probably didn't explain it well. I know how to compute the area that each of the cones delimites on the sphere ($4\alpha_1$ and $4\alpha_2$ if we consider the sphere to be the unit sphere, right?), but I don't know how to compute the area of the intersection, on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: @toliveira, sorry, I forgot to tag you in my previous comment, and I can't figure out how to edit it.

Comment: What is the big circle?

Comment: @zoli, do you mean the big circle that is in the first picture or in the second one? In the first figure, it is the equator of the sphere (the intersection of the sphere with the plane XY), and in the second one, it's the intersection of the sphere with the YZ plane. (I just draw the second picture because the shape of the intersection didn't seem too clear in the first one).

Comment: @toliveira, I just noticed I wrote a mistake in my first comment. I intended to say that the area is on the sphere. I'm sorry :(

Comment: @WildFeather, I would try to: 1) express the blue circle in spherical coordinates; 2) express the red circle in spherical coordinates; 3) find an expression for the two lines delimiting the surface on the sphere. I haven't found out yet how to do (2).

Comment: @toliveira, but can you express the blue circle in spherical coordinates? Do you know how the equation of the blue cone would be? If you know how to do that, I think I can find the equation of the second cone (the red one), supposing that its axis is the OZ axis and then applying a rotation matrix. Thank you!

Comment: @WildFeather, the equation of the blue circle in spherical coordinates is (R,θ,α1), where R is the radius of the sphere, θ∈[0,2π]. Note that by θ in this comment is a dummy variable and not the one you have drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question can be answered with spherical geometry. In the notation of the question, and referring to the diagram, the circle of angular radius $\alpha_{1}$ centered at $p_{1}$ and the circle of angular radius $\alpha_{2}$ centered at $p_{2}$ meet at $p_{3}$ and $p_{4}$. The segments shown are great circle arcs.

[image: The spherical digon enclosed by two circles]

1. The area sought is the area of the spherical sector $p_{1} p_{3} p_{4}$ plus the area of the sector $p_{2} p_{4} p_{3}$ minus the area of the spherical quadrilateral $p_{1} p_{3} p_{2} p_{4}$.
2. If $\phi_{1} = \angle p_{4} p_{1} p_{3}$ is the "apex" angle of the spherical triangle $\triangle p_{1} p_{3} p_{4}$, the area of the spherical sector $p_{1} p_{3} p_{4}$ is $\phi_{1}(1 - \cos \alpha_{1})$ by [Archimedes' hat box theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesHat-BoxTheorem.html).

   Similarly, if $\phi_{2} = \angle p_{3} p_{2} p_{4}$, the area of the spherical sector $p_{2} p_{4} p_{3}$ is $\phi_{2}(1 - \cos \alpha_{2})$.
3. If $\psi_{1} = \angle p_{1} p_{3} p_{4}$ and $\psi_{2} = \angle p_{2} p_{4} p_{3}$ are the "base" angles of the spherical triangles, the spherical quadrilateral $p_{1} p_{3} p_{2} p_{4}$ has area $\phi_{1} + \phi_{2} + 2(\psi_{1} + \psi_{2}) - 2\pi$.

Putting everything together, your "digon" has area
\begin{multline*}
  \phi_{1}(1 - \cos\alpha_{1}) + \phi_{2}(1 - \cos\alpha_{2}) - \bigl[\phi_{1} + \phi_{2} + 2(\psi_{1} + \psi_{2}) - 2\pi\bigr] \\
  = 2\pi - 2(\psi_{1} + \psi_{2}) - \phi_{1} \cos\alpha_{1} - \phi_{2} \cos\alpha_{2}.
\end{multline*}

If $A$, $B$, $C$ are points on the unit sphere, the normalized cross products
$$
n_{B} = \frac{A \times (B - A)}{\|A \times (B - A)\|},\qquad
n_{C} = \frac{A \times (C - A)}{\|A \times (C - A)\|}
$$
are perpendicular to the planes through $O$, $A$, $B$ and $O$, $A$, $C$ respectively, so
$$
\angle CAB = \arccos(n_{B} \cdot n_{C}).
\tag{1}
$$

To express this completely in terms of $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{2}$, and $\theta$, use Cartesian coordinates with
\begin{align*}
  p_{1} &= (0, 0, 1), \\
  p_{2} &= (\sin\theta, 0, \cos\theta), \\
  p_{3} &= (a, -b, \cos\alpha_{1}), \\
  p_{4} &= (a, \phantom{-}b, \cos\alpha_{1}).
\end{align*}
The condition $p_{2} \cdot p_{3} = \cos\alpha_{2}$ gives
$$
a = \frac{\cos\alpha_{2} - \cos\alpha_{1} \cos\theta}{\sin\theta},
$$
and then
$$
b = \sqrt{\sin^{2}\alpha_{1} - a^{2}}.
$$
Equation (1) now gives the angles $\phi_{i} = \angle p_{3} p_{i} p_{4}$ and $\psi_{i} = p_{3} p_{4} p_{i}$ in terms of $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{2}$, and $\theta$.

(I haven't tried to substitute everything and simplify.)

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is awesome! I'm still trying to understand all the details and complete the calculations. But in the expressions of the points $p_2$, $p_3$ and $p_4$, didn't you interchange the axes OX and OY? I usually consider OY to be the axis that points to the right in my diagram, but you seem to take that one as the OX axis.

Comment: Ah, yes, you did say the cone axes were in the $(y, z)$-plane. Swapping the first two coordinates reconciles things with your notation (though of course the area is the same either way). ;)

Comment: The only part of your answer that I don't completely get is when you use the Archimedes' hat box theorem to deduce an expression for the area of the two spherical triangles. Maybe I'm asking for too much, but I would be really grateful if you could explain it a little more. I understand the theorem, but how do you deduce the expression for the area of the triangle from there? Thank you again! :)

Comment: A cone of (half-)angle $\alpha$ cuts out a zone of sphere whose height along the cone axis is $1 - \cos\alpha$, and whose area is therefore $2\pi(1 - \cos\alpha)$. The area of a sector is proportional to the "apex" angle $\phi$, hence is $$(\phi/2\pi)2\pi(1 - \cos\alpha) = \phi(1 - \cos\alpha).$$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, could you please tell us how you created the figure?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I suppose I'm doing something wrong, but if I'm understanding Archimedes' hat box theorem correctly, my reasoning would be the following: if we consider the plane that contains the equator of the sphere, and the plane that contains the circle which passes through $p_1$, $p_3$ and $p_4$, these planes cut a "band" on the sphere whose area is $2\pi(cos\alpha_1$. Since the area of the unit sphere is $4\pi$, the area of the circle would be $(4\pi-4\pi(1-cos\alpha_1))/2=2\pi*cos\alpha_1$, and the area of the spherical sector $p_1p_3p_4$ would be $\phi_1*cos\alpha_1$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @toliveira: I used [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html).

Comment: @WildFeather: If $\alpha_{1} = 0$, the spherical cap has area zero, not $2\pi$, and if $\alpha > \pi/2$, the area is positive. ;) In my previous comment, I probably should have written that one nappe of a cone of half-angle $\alpha$ cuts out a spherical _cap_ of area $2\pi(1 - \cos\alpha)$. (This cap is technically a "zone", but "zone" might suggest the complement of the cap.) In your calculation, if you replace $1 - \cos\alpha$ with $\cos\alpha$, the area of the sector comes out correctly.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oh, sorry, I did a stupid mistake, I though the height of the "band" that the cone cuts on the sphere would be $1-cos\alpha$, but it's obviously just $cos\alpha$. Thank you so much for the clarification! Now I think I understand everything except why the area of the spherical quadrilateral $p_1p_3p_2p_4$ is as you say, but I'll believe you ;) I wish your answer would get more upvotes, it's truly great! And the figure is impressive too, I'm going to try to replicate it myself but I doubt I'll make it :( Thanks again!

Comment: The claim about the area of a quadrilateral comes from a fundamental property of spherical (geodesic) triangles, itself a special case of the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Triangles) (but admitting an elementary proof along the lines of this post): The [area is proportional to their angular defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess). Dividing the quadrilateral into two triangles gives the stated property.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you, I understand it now! I'm trying to study the case when the axis of the second cone is inside the "cap" that the first one cuts on the sphere (I hadn't thought of that before), do you think I should ask another question about it? It seems unfair to keep asking here, right? I don't know what I should do, since I'm quite new here...

Comment: The "other" case turns out not to be when the axis of one cone is inside the other, but when one or both sectors subtend an angle greater than $\pi$. In this event, more-or-less the same formula holds, aside from signs on square roots. (It may be easiest to express the area of a "segment" of a spherical cap cut by a chord, and to view your digon as a union of two such segments.)