# Area of intersection between cone and plane

Tags: plane-geometry, solid-geometry

Assume that a plane and a cone intersect, e.g., $(z-z_0)^2=x^2 + y^2$, and $z=-y+f(t)$. I can find that the intersection of these two objects would be equal to $y=\frac{x^2-[f(t)]^2+2z_0f(t)-z_0^2}{2z_0-2f(t)}$.

I am trying to find an expression for the area within the parabola which would be projected on the $z=-y+f(t)$ plane, and as that plane moves relative to the cone (hence the f(t) term).

This problem is similar to this [Area of the intersection of two cones](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180406/area-of-the-intersection-of-two-cones) problem, where my plane would be the plane through the points $p_3$, $p_4$, and the origin.

Comment: What does the f(t) in z= -z+ f(t) mean?  Is that a different plane for different values of t?

Comment: The intersection is a parabola, which has infinite area.

Comment: @Aretino - sorry, to clarify, I intended that the cone was bounded on the bottom by the X-Y plane.

Comment: @user247327 - the f(t) term is a parameter that I will use to move the plane with reference to the z-axis.

Answer (score 0):

In diagram below, line $OC$ is the $z$-axis and line $OE$ is the $y$-axis.

From your data it follows that $CO=OD=OE=z_0$ and $BO=OH=f(t)$. It is then quite easy to compute
$$
VH={z_0+f(t)\over\sqrt2}
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
AH=\sqrt{HD\cdot HE}=\sqrt{z_0^2-f(t)^2}.
$$
Finally, as Archimedes of Syracuse proved many years ago, the area of the parabola segment is given by
$$
area={4\over3}AH\cdot VH=
{4\over3}\sqrt{z_0^2-f(t)^2}{z_0+f(t)\over\sqrt2}.
$$

[image]